# Catch multiple errorTypes?

Tags: swift, error-handling, switch-statement

I'm looking for a way to catch multiple types of errors in a `catch`. I've tried `fallthrough` and the comma separated style from a switch statement and neither works. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) say nothing about catching multiple but [`pattern 1`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID419). It's not clear to me which of the pattern syntaxes would work here.

Error definitions (sample):

```
enum AppErrors {
  case NotFound(objectType: String, id: Int)
  case AlreadyUsed
}
```

Works:

```
do {
  //...
} catch AppErrors.NotFound {
  makeNewOne()
} catch AppErrors.AlreadyUsed {
  makeNewOne()
} catch {
  print("Unhandled error: \(error)")
}
```

Does not compile, is it possible to do something like this?

```
do {
  //...
} catch AppErrors.NotFound, AppErrors.AlreadyUsed {
  makeNewOne()
} catch {
  print("Unhandled error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want to catch all `AppErrors`, you can use this pattern:

```
catch is AppErrors
```

If you're looking for more specific matching, it seems to quickly get ugly.

This will let us catch specific cases of `AppErrors`:

```
catch let error as AppErrors where error == .NotFound || error == .AlreadyUsed
```

There's also this syntax which seems to work:

```
catch let error as AppErrors where [.NotFound, .AlreadyUsed].contains(error)
```

For completeness sake, I'll also add this option, which allows us to catch errors of two different types, but it doesn't allow us to specify which case within those types:

```
catch let error where error is AppErrors || error is NSError
```

---

Finally, based on the fact that *anything* we catch will conform to the `ErrorType` protocol, we can clean up the second & third examples I provided with an `ErrorType` extension and use that in conjunction where a `where` clause in our `catch`:

```
extension ErrorType {
    var isFooError: Bool {
        guard let err = self as? AppErrors else { return false }
        return err == .NotFound || err == .AlreadyUsed
    }
}
```

And just catch it like this:

```
catch let error where error.isFooError
```

Comment: When I try `catch let error as AppErrors where error == .NotFound`, I get the error message `binary operator == cannot be applied to two AppErrors operands`. I think this is because these errorTypes have associated values. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think the `ErrorType` extension at the bottom of answer can probably work for that.

Comment: Since it uses a `==` implementation for comparison, it doesn't work either. Right now I think only a switch implementation can package up multiple associated-value errorTypes.

Comment: You can put whatever logic you want in the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-Pattern Catch Clauses proposal ([SE-0276](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0276-multi-pattern-catch-clauses.md)) is implemented in [Swift 5.3](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.3-released/#new-features-and-refinements)

And now code snippet from the question is valid:

```
do {
  //...
} catch AppErrors.NotFound, AppErrors.AlreadyUsed {
  makeNewOne()
} catch {
  print("Unhandled error: \(error)")
}
```

You can check updated [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID541).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a case that contains an `AppErrors` array:

```
indirect enum AppErrors: Error {
  case NotFound
  case AlreadyUsed
  case errors([AppErrors])
}
```

Then, for the catch statement:

```
catch AppErrors.errors(let errors) where errors == [.NotFound, .AlreadyUsed]
```

Do note, however, that `errors` is an `Array` and the *order matters* when comparing with `==`. An alternative is to use `case errors(Set<AppErrors>)`, but that would require `AppErrors` to conform to `Hashable` protocol.

**UPDATE:** Come to think of it, it's better to use an `OptionSet` type:

```
public struct InvalidInput: OptionSet, Error {
    public var rawValue: Int

    public init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    public static let noAccount  = InvalidInput(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    public static let noKey      = InvalidInput(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    public static let invalidKey = InvalidInput(rawValue: 1 << 2)
}

func validateInput() throws -> Void {
    var invalid: InvalidInput = []

    invalid.insert(.noKey)
    invalid.insert(.noAccount)

    if !invalid.isEmpty {
        throw invalid
    }
}

do {
    try validateInput()
} catch [InvalidInput.noAccount, InvalidInput.noKey] as InvalidInput {
    print("Account and key are both required.")
}
```

Link: http://www.chrisamanse.xyz/2016/12/03/catching-multiple-errors-in-swift